# How can I set key-value pair in NSMutableDictionary as XML attribute-element values using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, nsxmlparser

I am using **NSXMLParser** to parse my XML with the following structure:

```
<characters>
    <character>
        <literal>本</literal>
        <codepoint>
            <cp_value cp_type="ucs">672c</cp_value>
            <cp_value cp_type="jis208">43-60</cp_value>
        </codepoint>
    </character>
</characters>
```

I want to use the `cp_value` element's attribute_value as a key and the element value (e.g. 672c) as the value and place this key-value pair in my `NSMutableDictionary` `*_codepoint`. After parsing, I want the result (in the console) to look like this:

```
_codepoint: {
 "ucs"=672c;
 "jis208"=43-60;
}
```

As I have implemented the parser (code follows), I am getting this back in the console:

```
2013-01-22 22:12:46.199 MyApp[13391:c07] _codepoint: {
ucs = "\n        \n            ";
}
2013-01-22 22:12:46.201 MyApp[13391:c07] _codepoint: {
    jis208 = "\n        \n            672c\n            ";
}
```

First - the values and keys are out-of-sync and second, the value for the jis208 element is not getting read-in. Second, I'm not sure what these \n and whitespaces are. Can anybody please give some advice?

The code I have written is:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"characters"]) {
        appDelegate.characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"character"]) {
        aCharacter = [[Character alloc] init];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"cp_value"]) {
        if (!_codepoint) _codepoint = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_codepoint setValue:currentElementValue forKey:[attributeDict valueForKey:[[attributeDict allKeys] lastObject]]];
        NSLog(@"_codepoint: %@", _codepoint);
    }
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!currentElementValue) {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    } else {
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"characters"]
        // cp_values will be copied from a local NSMutableDictionary *_codepoint
        || [elementName isEqualToString:@"codepoint"]
        ) return;    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"character"]) {
        [appDelegate.characters addObject:aCharacter];
        [aCharacter release];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"cp_value"]){
        [aCharacter.codepoint addObject:_codepoint];
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is that you are adding **currentElementValue** to **_codepoint** before reading actual value into **currentElementValue** i.e you are adding it in when **cp_value** is started. you should add **currentElementValue** to **_codepoint** in `didEndElement:` delegate method.Then you'll get expected result.Modify your code like this:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"characters"]) {
        appDelegate.characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"character"]) {
        aCharacter = [[Character alloc] init];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"cp_value"]) {
        if (!_codepoint) _codepoint = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    currentAttributeKey = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[attributeDict valueForKey:[[attributeDict allKeys] lastObject]]];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!currentElementValue) {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    } else {
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"characters"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"codepoint"]) 
        return;    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"character"]) {
        [appDelegate.characters addObject:aCharacter];
        [aCharacter release];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"cp_value"]){
        [_codepoint setValue:[[currentElementValue componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""] forKey:currentAttributeKey];
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        NSLog(@"_codepoint: %@", _codepoint);
        [aCharacter.codepoint addObject:_codepoint];
    }
}
```

where **currentAttributeKey** is NSMutableString that will store the attributes.In your case **ucs**  and **jis208**

Comment: Pratyusha, Thank you very much! Your solution worked perfectly. I still want to understand about the \n's and all that whitespace. Why does that get output in the console?

Comment: My pleasure. After finding a character after start of the element you are appending it to `currentElementValue`.After every tag for example `characters` we have a new line so \n is getting appended to `currentElementValue`.thank u for accepting :)

Comment: Sorry it's late, but thank you - this is exactly right.